# Get Data from POST-SUBMIT

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, dynamic-forms

I have a view strongly-typed with the model **VersaoUpload** called **index** and this model has a member **IEnumerable ArqUpload** that contain two fields typed string.

The view index has a button to add dynamic field, when I click on this button, Code render a partial view strongly-typed **ArqUpload** called **FileEditBox** to add the field.

But I don't get the data of the dynamic fields.

View **Index**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"  
                     Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<UPDATE.ViewModels.VersaoUpload>" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>Index</h2>

<% using(Html.BeginForm()) { %>


     <div id="editorRows">
            <% foreach (var item in Model.Arqs)

                Html.RenderPartial("FileEditRow", item);
            %>
     </div>

     <%= Html.ActionLink("Add another...", "Add", null, new { id = "addItem" }) %>


     <% } %>

</asp:Content>
```

View FileEditBox:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"  Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<UPDATE.ViewModels.ArqUpload>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="UPDATE.Helpers"%>

<div class="editorRow">
    <% using(Html.BeginCollectionItem("files")) { %>
        Arquivo: <%= Html.FileBoxFor(x => x.Arquivo)   %>
        Tipo:
        <%=Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Tipo,"1")%> Sql
        <%=Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Tipo,"2")%> Package
        <%=Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Tipo,"3")%> Config
        <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
    <% } %>
</div>
```

The Controller:

```
 public ViewResult Add()
    {
        return View("FileEditRow", new ArqUpload());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(VersaoUpload versao)
    {

        // To do: do whatever you want with the data
        return View("Resultado",versao);
    }
```

And this is the view Resultado to view the result:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<UPDATE.ViewModels.VersaoUpload>" %>
 <% foreach (ArqUpload it in Model.Arqs)
       { %>
    <div class="display-label">Tipo Arquvo</div>
    <div class="display-field"><%: it.Tipo %></div>
    <% } %>
```

But, the it.Tipo is null.